# Can't execute xrandr command in crontab(even with $DISPLAY arg supplied)

Tags: linux, unix, cron, xrandr

I have the following script(/home/vitidn/Downloads/adjust_contrast.sh) to adjust display contrast:

```
#!/bin/sh

export DISPLAY=":0"
echo "adjust the display..."
xrandr --display :0 --output eDP1 --prop --verbose --gamma 0.5:0.5:0.45
```

it works fine if I run from cmd line but failed to run from crontab

It also has all perms:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 167 Jan  8 10:04 /home/vitidn/Downloads/adjust_contrast.sh
```

I create a crontab(with sudo) with the following content:

```
* * * * * /home/vitidn/Downloads/adjust_contrast.sh > /tmp/adjust_contrast.output
```

In /tmp/adjust_contrast.output, the script is run accordingly but part of xrandr otuput is no where to be found:

```
adjust the display...
```

I suspect that it has somethings to do with a permission but still can't pinpoint it.

Thank you for your helps

Comment: If you append `2>&1` to your crontab line, it'll log the error messages as well

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, now I am able to find the cause of this problem. Add the following permission to the script solved this issue:        export XAUTHORITY=/home/vitidn/.Xauthority

Comment: If you don't want to delete this question (which I would, on the basis that it's off-topic being more about system administration than programming), I'd suggest adding an answer yourself; you can then accept that answer after the timeout passes. Editing answers into questions tends to be frowned on here (as it circumvents the mechanisms in place to allow the community to vote/delete/close/&c answers independently of questions).

Comment: reference here， same question and better answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102389/xrandr-not-working-on-crontab?newreg=5a73c82c921a457c90b5075a99aed548

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** add the following permission to my script solved my problem(get it from env)

```
export XAUTHORITY=/home/vitidn/.Xauthority
```